# Registration success with database record but unable to login

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't login always. Login failed even when the input are correct moreover I can see it in the database

```
<?php
    require "konfig.php";

    $errors = array();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    if(preg_match("/\S+/", $_POST['fname']) === 0){
        $errors['fname'] = "* First Name is required.";
    }
    if(preg_match("/\S+/", $_POST['lname']) === 0){
        $errors['lname'] = "* Last Name is required.";
    }
    if(preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/", $_POST['email']) === 0){
        $errors['email'] = "* Not a valid e-mail address.";
    }
    if(preg_match("/.{8,}/", $_POST['password']) === 0){
        $errors['password'] = "* Password Must Contain at least 8 Chanacters.";
    }
    if(strcmp($_POST['password'], $_POST['confirm_password'])){
        $errors['confirm_password'] = "* Password do not much.";
    }
     if (!isset($_POST['gen'])) {  
     $errors['gen'] = "specify your gender"; 
      }  
   else {  
     $gen = ($_POST['gen']);  
   }  
    if(count($errors) === 0){
        $fname =  $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $gen = $_POST['gen'];

        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
        function createSalt(){
            $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            return substr($string, 0, 3);
        }
        $salt = createSalt();
        $password = hash('sha256', $salt . $password);

        $qt = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'";
        $search =$dbc->prepare($qt);
     $search->bindParam(':email',$email);
        $search->execute();
        $num_row = $search->rowCount();
        if($num_row >= 1){
            $errors['email'] = "Email address is unavailable.";
        }else{

            $sql = $dbc->prepare ("insert into members(fname,lname,email,salt,password,gen) values (:fname, :lname, :email, :salt, :password,:gen)");
             $sql->bindParam(':fname',$fname);
                $sql->bindParam(':lname',$lname);
                $sql->bindParam(':email',$email);
                $sql->bindParam(':salt',$salt);
                 $sql->bindParam(':password',$password);
                  $sql->bindParam(':gen',$gen);
                  $sql->execute();
            $successful = "<h3> You are successfully registered.</h3>";
        }
    }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="login">
        <form method="post" action="login.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><h1>E-mail</h1></td>
                    <td><h1>Password</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="login_email" id="login_email"></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" value="Login"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><?php if(isset($_GET['message'])){ echo "<h2>" .$_GET['message']. "</h2>"; } ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php if(isset($successful)){ echo $successful; } ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])){echo $_POST['fname'];} ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lname'])){echo $_POST['lname'];} ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php if(isset($errors['fname'])){echo "<h2>" .$errors['fname']. "</h2>"; } ?></td>
                    <td><?php if(isset($errors['lname'])){echo "<h2>" .$errors['lname']. "</h2>"; } ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr">
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){echo $_POST['email'];} ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php if(isset($errors['email'])){echo "<h2>" .$errors['email']. "</h2>"; } ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="password" id="pw" placeholder="Password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php if(isset($errors['password'])){echo "<h2>" .$errors['password']. "</h2>"; } ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="cpw" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php if(isset($errors['confirm_password'])){echo "<h2>" .$errors['confirm_password']. "</h2>"; } ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><b>SEX</b></td>  
 <td>  
 <input type="radio" name="gen" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male" id= "rgm">Male  
 <input type="radio" name="gen" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female" id="rgf">Female  
 <td colspan="2"><?php if(isset($errors['gen'])){echo "<h2>" .$errors['gen']. "</h2>"; } ?></td>

 </td>  
 </tr>  
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



    session_start();

    $email = $_POST['login_email'];
    $password = $_POST['login_password'];

    require "konfig.php";
    $sql = "SELECT password, salt FROM members WHERE email = :email";
    $query = $dbc->prepare($sql);
     $query->bindParam(':email',$email);
     $query->execute();
     $rows = $query->rowCount();
    if($rows < 1) {
        $message = "Login Failed!";
        header("location: index.php?message=". $message);
    }
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $row['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
    if($hash != $row['password']){
        $message = "Login Failed!";
        header("location: index.php?message=". $message);
    }else{
        session_regenerate_id ();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header("location: home.php");
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<body>
```

Comment: am alwas getin login failed please i need help

Comment: what say a print_r( $row ) and your generated hash at this moment?

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: @blub i dont really get what you saying what did you suggest i should do? or where should i modify?

Comment: @jay what way should i use...but i dont think thats preventing it from loging in

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or youi can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: am using pdo @jay not mysqli

Comment: Ah, that wasn't totally clear. You should implement [PDO Error Checking](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: i did that in my konfig.php.

Comment: <?Php
$host_name = "localhost";
$database = "form_validation"; 
$username = "root";         
$password = "";          


try {
$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>

Comment: edited title to be clearer.